# How to fetch related data from Directus using the API and display it in a Next.js application?

Tags: next.js, supabase, directus

I'm working on a Next.js application and using Directus as my headless CMS. I have three tables in Directus: Concept, Definitionc, and Definitionl. The relationships between these tables are as follows:

Each Concept can have multiple Definitioncs and Definitionls.
Both Definitionc and Definitionl have a foreign key to the Concept table.
I'm trying to fetch a Concept by its slug, along with its related Definitioncs and Definitionls using the Directus API. I want to display the fetched data in my Next.js application.

Here's my current code for fetching the data:

```
// Fetching Concept data
const { data: conceptData, error: conceptError } = useSWR(
  slug
    ? `http://0.0.0.0:8055/items/Concept?filter[concept_slug][_eq]=${slug}&fields=id,concept_title,concept_categorie.categorie_title`
    : null,
  conditionalFetcher
);

// Fetching related Definitionc data
const { data: definitionsCData, error: definitionsCError } = useSWR(
  slug && slug.length > 0 ? ['definitionsC', slug] : null,
  (key, slug) => fetchDefinitionsC(slug)
);

// Fetching related Definitionl data
const { data: definitionsLData, error: definitionsLError } = useSWR(
  slug && slug.length > 0 ? ['definitionsL', slug] : null,
  (key, slug) => fetchDefinitionsL(slug)
);
```

I'm facing a problem where the related Definitionc and Definitionl data is not being fetched or displayed. I get undefined values for definitionsCData and definitionsLData. The Concept data is being fetched correctly, but the related data is not.

I have tried various combinations of API requests and parameters, but I'm still unable to fetch the related data. The Directus API returns a 403 (Forbidden) or a 400 (Bad Request) error for some of the requests.

How can I correctly fetch the related Definitionc and Definitionl data from the Directus API and display it in my Next.js application?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Other details :

- I'm sure the API token is correct, as I'm using the same one to fetch concepts.
- API token has read access to Concept, Definitionc, and DefinitionL.
- Database is hosted on Supabase. No RLS enabled as of now.
- For another relation, Concept and Category (Each concept has only 1 category), a new junction table was automatically created in Supabase : Concept_Category. The same did **not** happen for the relation between Defibitionc and Concept, and Definitionl and Concept.